# How to import a column of a CSV file into a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, bash, csv, terminal

My goal is to import a one column of a CSV file into a Ruby array. This is for a self-contained Ruby script, not an application. I'll just be running the script in Terminal and getting an output.

I'm having trouble finding the best way to import the file and finding the best way to dynamically insert the name of the file into that line of code. The filename will be different each time, and will be passed in by the user. I'm using `$stdin.gets.chomp` to ask the user for the filename, and setting it equal to `file_name`.

Can someone help me with this? Here's what I have for this part of the script:

```
require 'csv'
    zip_array = CSV.read("path/to/file_name.csv")
```

and I need to be able to insert the proper file path above. Is this correct? And how do I get that path name in there? Maybe I'll need to totally re-structure my script, but any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Programs that ask for input are typically super annoying. Why not make the filename a command-line argument? Those are available in `ARGV`.

Comment: You can use Dir.glob("*.csv")[0] if that file (doesn't matter the name) will be the only csv file in your program folder. That way you don't have to worry about the name changing all the time.

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here, I think. The first is about getting user input from the command line. The usual way to do this is with `ARGV`. In your program you could do `file_name = ARGV[0]` so a user could type `ruby your_program.rb path/to/file_name.csv` on the command line.

The next is about reading CSVs. Using `CSV.read` will take the whole CSV, not just a single column. If you want to choose one column of many, you are likely better off doing:

```
zip_array = []
CSV.foreach(file_name) { |row| zip_array << row[whichever_column] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first problem:

a) The file name will be different on each run (I'm supposing it will always be a CSV file, right?)

You can solve this problem with creating a folder, say input_data inside your Ruby script. Then do:

```
Dir.glob('input_data/*.csv')
```

This will produce an array of ALL files inside that folder that end with CSV. If we assume there will be only 1 file at a time in that folder (with a different name), we can do:

```
file_name = Dir.glob('input_data/*.csv')[0]
```

This way you'll dynamically get the file path, no matter what the file is named. If the csv file is inside the same directory as your Ruby script, you can just do:

```
Dir.glob('*.csv')[0]
```

Now, for importing only 1 column into a Ruby array (let's suppose it's the first column):

```
require 'csv'
array = []
CSV.foreach(file_name) do |csv_row|
  array << csv_row[0] # [0] for the first column, [1] for the second etc.
end
```

What if your CSV file has headers? Suppose your column name is 'Total'. You can do:

```
require 'csv'
array = []
CSV.foreach(file_name, headers: true) do |csv_row|
  array << csv_row['Total']
end
```

Now it doesn't matter if your column is the 1st column, the 3rd etc, as long as it has a header named 'Total', Ruby will find it.

CSV.foreach reads your file line-by-line and is good for big files. CSV.read will read it at once but  using it you can make your code more concise:

```
array = CSV.read(, headers: true).map do |csv_row|
  csv_row['Total']
end
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign the returned value from `$stdin.gets.chomp` to a variable:

```
foo = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Which will assign the entered input to `foo`.

You don't need to use `$stdin` though, as `gets` will use the standard input channel by default:

```
foo = gets.chomp
```

At that point use the variable as your `read` parameter:

```
zip_array = CSV.read(foo)
```

That's all basic coding and covered in any intro book for a language.